# Cufon differences on dev-server and published version

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, cufon

i made a webapplication with asp.net mvc 2 and used cufon to make some fonts "prettier"

when i view the website local with the development server in visual studio everything works fine and the fonts and all characters are shown correctly (some parts are in german so i have some special signs like äöü etc.) 
now i published the site to my server and that also works fine but now the special characters aren't shown in cufon transformed texts. also the texts are a little bit bigger on the published version than the local.

i checked if both js files are the same and they are.

any ideas where the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mmmh the characters problem seems to me an encoding problem. Maybe locally you use UTF and on the server there is a different encoding... what if you try to encode the special characters using the respective character entity reference? (see http://www.chami.com/tips/internet/050798i.html )

The fonts to be bigger, really strange. Are you sure that the CSS is exactly the same locally and server side? (Try to compare using Firebug).

Hope this helps...